# Why ldapsearch is not working with anonymous bind after upgrading OpenLDAP to v2.4?

Tags: openldap

I have a setup of **OpenLDAP v2.3** which I am using for last few years. Following are the lines in `slapd.conf` for access control.

```
access to dn.one="o=abc, c=IN"
        by * read

access to dn.base="o=abc, c=IN"
        by * none
```

When I do ldapsearch using anonymous bind gives me result.

For example following command gives result.

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -b "o=abc,c=IN"
```

Now I upgraded the OS, CentOS from 5.5 to 6.3 so the version of OpenLDAP is **OpenLDAP v2.4**. We have not changed the schema.

But now the same `ldapsearch` gives me `result: 32 No such object` error.

But it works when I added following line in access control configuration.

```
access to dn.one="o=abc, c=IN"
        by * read

access to dn.base="o=abc, c=IN"
        by anonymous read
        by * none
```

What can be the reason? Is there any security risk in doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question on OpenLDAP mailing list and got the answer. Thanks to Pierangelo Masarati.

In OpenLDAP v2.4, search operation requires "search" privileges on the "entry" pseudo-attribute of the search base which was not the case in v2.3.

man slapd.access(5):

> [...]
>
> The  search operation, requires search (=s) privileges on the entry
>   pseudo-attribute of the searchBase (NOTE: *this was introduced with
>   OpenLDAP 2.4*).
>
> [...]

So I do not have to give read access to anonymous for base. Only
search privilege is enough as following.

```
access to dn.base="o=abc, c=IN"
            by anonymous search
            by * none
```

I tested it successfully.